# Wpf: How can I create a custom ListBox Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, wpf-controls

I wanted to create a menu bar in wpf like the ones on websites. It should have different menu items and per click you get to another page. The main point is, it should change the borders when hovering or clicking an item. So I thought a custom Listbox would be the best solution for my case. I don't want a usercontrol, it should be a custom control.

What I have:
I created a class that derives from ListBox:

```
public class MenuListBox : ListBox
{
    public MenuListBox()
    {

    }
}
```

And created a resource dictionary to template the listbox. I also added this as merged dictionary into the generic.xaml file.

```
<ResourceDictionary>

<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Controls:MenuListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

At this point I don't know how to continue. The box should also fire an event so I can change a page in frame or something. Does anyone know a good solution or any articles / tutorials? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WPF already has a menu object so there is no need for a custom control. Create a custom style for the menu and add it to your application resources.

See here for help on styling a menu: http://www.jimnuzzi.com/2008/06/29/wpf-xaml-menuitem-styles/